# Kernel boot command line altered in uefi mode

Tags: boot, 20.04, system-installation, uefi, grub-efi

I want to prepare custom installation ISO for Ubuntu 20.04 server that will use autoinstall feature to install system automatically. To achieve that I have to add this to the boot command:

```
autoinstall ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/preseed/
```

in the end the whole line in the grub.cfg looks like this:

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper quiet  autoinstall ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/preseed/ ---
```

When I set in bios legacy boot mode everything works fine. This command is taken into account and my scenario works well.
However, when uefi mode is set system installs in manual mode,like my change was not there. After I started to debug I can see that in fact boot command is changed and in /var/log/kern.log I can see that string:

`Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper quiet autoinstall ds=nocloud`

so this part is missing: `;s=/cdrom/preseed/`

How can I fix that, so my setup will work well also in uefi mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that data source parameter can be escaped. Single quotes fix the issue:

```
ds='nocloud;s=/cdrom/preseed/'
```

This way path to the autoinstall config files is picked properly even when uefi mode is used. It is a pity that this is not mentioned in any documentation, because part after ";" is a confusing problem.